# How to configure for autosuggest using Suggester component in solr?

Tags: c#, solr, autosuggest

I am using SolrNet to index and search on couple of tables.

I am able to search on complete word successfully.

Now, I am trying to implement the autosuggest feature wherein, the query will have a partial word or phrase rather than a complete word.

My Schema.xml looks like this

```xml
<fields>
    <!-- declare fields of entity class -->
    <!-- type will specify the table name -->
    <field name="type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"  />

    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true"/>

    <field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

    <!-- unique field -->
    <field name="uid" type="uuid" indexed="true" stored="true" />

  </fields>

  <uniqueKey>uid</uniqueKey>

  <copyField source="name" dest="text"/>

  <types>
    <fieldType name="uuid" class="solr.UUIDField" indexed="true" />
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />
    <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true"/>

    <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    .....
    </types>
```

And my solrconfig.xml look like

```xml
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
    <!-- a spellchecker built from a field of the main index -->
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">suggest</str>
      <str name="field">name</str>
      <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookup</str>
      <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>          
      <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
      <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
      <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
      int name="minPrefix">1</int>
      <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
      <int name="minQueryLength">4</int>
      <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float>
       <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">.01</float>      
    </lst>

    <!-- a spellchecker that can break or combine words.  See "/spell" handler below for usage -->
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">wordbreak</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.WordBreakSolrSpellChecker</str>
      <str name="field">name</str>
      <str name="combineWords">true</str>
      <str name="breakWords">true</str>
      <int name="maxChanges">10</int>
    </lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">text</str>
      <!-- Solr will use suggestions from both the 'default' spellchecker
           and from the 'wordbreak' spellchecker and combine them.
           collations (re-written queries) can include a combination of
           corrections from both spellcheckers -->
      <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suggest</str>
      <!--<str name="spellcheck.dictionary">wordbreak</str>-->
      <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>       
      <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>       
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>  
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>         
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

However, I am not getting any records in the output on search.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Curious - why is text multivalued, whereas name isn't?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the < in your minPrefix tag in solrconfig.xml

```
<int name="maxEdits">2</int>
int name="minPrefix">1</int>
<int name="maxInspections">5</int>
```